# data isn't displaying. ERROR: Cannot GET/ express API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, get

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data';


const app = express();

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
    res.send(data.products);
});

app.listen(5500, () => {console.log("Server started at http://localhost:5500");
});
```

This is my code in server.js and I've installed nodemon,babel-node,babel/preset-env and all, in .babelrc i have set the preset to @babel/preset-env and when i execute the command npm start. I am getting an error i.e., 'Cannot GET/' help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `/` route. Path not found on your server .That`s why you got error. Refer [Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router)

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(data.products);
});
```